# Unity3d: Modify Input Manager at RunTime (from C# script)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In most modern games, the player is able to choose its keys preferences at runtime. In Unity we can do so from the editor (Edit > Project Settings > Input) or before the game starts, but I was wondering if it was possible to do it at Runtime:

Something that would look like that:

```
InputManager.Axes.Horizontal.SetPositiveButton(KeyCode.Z);
```

I am asking that because I want to use `Input.GetAxis` in my PlayerController instead of `Input.GetKey()`

Comment: You will have to use a custom solution, or wait for the next [Input Manager](https://forum.unity.com/threads/welcome-new-input-system-resources-and-info-please-read.397153/) currently under development.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you where does the input manger save the input preferences when they are set from the window that appears before the game starts ? Cause those input modifications are persistent so it might be a good shortcut for me.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know where Unity is storing these information.